# How can I check the count of my tag wiki edits?

Tags: support, edits, tag-wiki

How can I check the count of my tag wiki edits?

I want to become "Research assistant" badge, and I would like to know how many edits did I do.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try e.g. this link:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/editing/info

[image]

There you see the stats including your tag edit statistics. I think that should be exactly what you want to see.

Answer (score 4):

Go to any [tag's info tab](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info). At the right side you can find the badge progress:

> [image]